# subsetting data frame with grep function returns wrong results

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have following csv file:

```
"id";"left.text";"left.ord";"right.text";"right.ord"
"AAA";n/a;n/a;"";1
"BAA";"- left";1;"";2
"CAA";"- left";2;"";3
"DAA";"x left";3;"";4
"EAA";"x left";4;"";5
"FAA";"x left";5;"";6
"GAA";"x left";6;"";7
"HAA";"x left";7;"";8
"IAA";n/a;n/a;"x";9
"JAA";n/a;n/a;"x";10
"KAA";n/a;n/a;"x";11
"LAA";n/a;n/a;"-";12
"MAA";n/a;n/a;"-";13
"NAA";n/a;n/a;"-";14
"OAA";n/a;n/a;"-";15
"PAA";"x left";8;"";16
"QAA";"- left";9;"";17
"RAA";n/a;n/a;"-";18
"SAA";n/a;n/a;"-";19
"TAA";n/a;n/a;"-";20
```

Which is loaded via

```
dframe <- read.csv(file="input.csv", header=T, sep=";", skip=0, check.names=TRUE, na.string = "n/a")
```

Following command works as expected and returns one record (where id is AAA):

```
res1 <- dframe[with(dframe, which(is.na(left.text) & right.text == "")), ]
```

But seems like if this one completely ignores part after ampersand and returns all `n/a` records from `left.text` column:

```
res2 <- dframe[with(dframe, which(is.na(left.text) & grep("^[:blank:]*$", right.text))), ]
```

Shouldn't 2nd command return the same as 1st?

PS: as `n/a` values are considered those which are explicitly marked in csv as `n/a` and not those which are blank.

Comment: Try `grepl` instead of `grep`.

Comment: A few issues here. 1) grepl/grep as above, 2) `[:blank:]` doesn't match `''`, it matches *"space and tab, and possibly other locale-dependent characters such as non-breaking space."* (see `?regexp`) 3) anyway you need double square brackets. Example: `grepl('^[[:blank:]]$', c(' ', ''))`

Comment: Thanks guys. Please post this as a an answer so I can accept it. Actually the using `grepl` is most important here and it works even with one square brackets, if you do not believe try: `is.na(dframe$left.text) & grepl("^[:blank:]*$", dframe$right.text)` vs `is.na(dframe$left.text) & grep("^[[:blank:]]*$", dframe$right.text)`.

Comment: May I ask why I've been down voted? Please make statement so I can correct the shortcomings. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why downvotes. Added comment as answer tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as answer as per request. A few issues here:

- grepl/grep as @fishtank said (`grep` returns numeric index, use `grepl` which returns logical if you want to apply boolean operations)
- `[:blank:]` doesn't match `''`, it matches *"space and tab, and possibly other locale-dependent characters such as non-breaking space."* (see `?regexp`)
- anyway you need double square brackets. Example: `grepl('^[[:blank:]]$', c(' ', ''))`

Bottom line: the observed behavior for the attempt at subsetting with grep is as expected. Stick with your first formulation, but you can drop the `which` call, since a logical vector is just as good for subsetting as a numeric vector:

```
dframe[with(dframe, is.na(left.text) & right.text == ""), ]
```